# Is there a comfortable way to generate efficient raster catalogs in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, performance, raster-catalog

Is there a comfortable way to generate efficient raster catalogs (such as in Arcgis), where polygon tiles are loaded as long as the scale does not hit a threshold value and images are only loaded when the scale is large enough?

I tried to compute a virtual raster in QGIS, but it did not work for 200 tiles and gave me error messages reproduced by other users as well. Loading all the single tiles into QGIS is not an option since these are rendered (extremely slowly) on any action I do within QGIS. Is there a perfomant solution embedding large raster data into QGIS projects without sacrificing too much performance?

QGIS can´t read and correctly open Esri raster catalogs.

Comment: If you right-click your raster and go to `Properties > General > Scale dependent visibility`, you can set your thresholds. Or you could try creating `Properties > Pyramids`.

Comment: thanks joseph, i can´t set scale-dependent visibility for a group of rasters though. Setting this for every single tile is just not efficient

Comment: Please add one such error message. You can also try the command line utility http://www.gdal.org/gdalbuildvrt.html `gdalbuildvrt output.vrt *.tif` Perhaps all your images are not similar when it comes to number of bands, projection, color interpretation...

Comment: The error message is: "The process failed to start. Either the invoked program is missing, or you may have insufficient permissions to invoke the program." It works when taking less, let´s say 10, tiles. But once agian, that´s not practical at all

Comment: Just tried gdalbuildvrt. Took 2 minutes to index 700 tif files. For making everything fast you must a) have tiled original images b) have overviews in the original images and c) build overviews for the whole vrt file.

Comment: thanx for your efforts! did you youse the command line version or the GUI? Can you explain what you did? I have tiled raw data (jpg) and as i said, gdalbuildvrt (GUI) did not help me out